# MapForce XSLT auto increment number every time it runs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, map-force

I been trying to add auto incremented number to one of the xml elements using Map Force

```
<seqNumber><seqNumber>
```

The existing function in the Map Force called "auto-number" does this already but I want my numbers restart at 99. In other words the numbers can be between 0 and 99.  I already thought about using MOD operation but the application would run for years in a mission critical production environment, we cant afford it to run out of size. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you believe that using `mod` would cause the application to run out of space?

Comment: I dont know the limitations of auto-number method in Map Force, that's all what I meant by it. cheers.